# Handlebars js editor.

Tags: eclipse, ember.js, handlebars.js

Lately I have started to explore Ember.js, from their site I understood that there is a good synergy between Ember and Handlebars language.

I wondered if there is any editor (plugin) that can help me with handlebars auto-completion and coloring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Sublime Text 2, there is a great Handlebars package for syntax highlighting, etc.

https://github.com/nrw/sublime-text-handlebars

TextMate version:

https://github.com/drnic/Handlebars.tmbundle

It can be installed manually or with the Sublime Text 2 package manager.

Comment: DO you know is there any project running for eclipse plugin?

Comment: As far as I know, a Handlebars syntax highlighting tool for Eclipse does not exist.

Comment: I'm tempted to down vote. But I didn't because - even it's tagged as eclipse - it's not mentioned once in the question itself.

Answer (score 18):

If you are using handlebars as .hbs files (no script tag) you can enable syntax highlight by configuring 2 settings:  the editor and content types:

- Eclipse -> Preferences -> General -> Content_Types
- add *.hbs under html
- Eclipse -> Preferences -> General -> Editor -> File Associations
- Add *.hbs to html editor.
- Close the editor and re-open it
- [optional] If still not highlight (old eclipse versions) restart eclipse.

This works for aptana and zend studio as well

Comment: It works with Eclipse Oxygen by just closing my `.hbs` file and reopening it.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA (an alternative to Eclipse) has a handlebars plug-in. For Emblem, a Haml-like version of Handlebars, the nearest plug-in would be Slim.